# Attempting to use Mode Wrap in Cuda

Tags: cuda

I'm attempting to use the `cudaAddressModeWrap` function in Cuda, however, I'm having some difficulties.

I have included my code below:

```
texture <float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;

__global__ void transformKernel( float* Btmp, int width, int height)
{
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  if ( (x < width) && (y < height) )
  {
    if( x == 0 || x == 1 )
      Btmp[y*width+x] = tex2D(tex, x, y);
    else
    {
      Btmp[y*width+x] = tex2D(tex, x, y) + \
        (0.15 * tex2D(tex, x - 2, y))    + \
        (0.65 * tex2D(tex, x - 1, y))    + \
        (1.35 * tex2D(tex, x + 1, y))    + \
        (1.85 * tex2D(tex, x + 2, y));
      Btmp[y * width + x] /= float(5);
    }   
  }
}
```

I want periodic boundary conditions so Mode Wrap should be perfect for this. I think I am setting up the parameter incorrectly but I'm not sure. Here is the relevant code.

```
  int i, j;
  float **A;
  float *Atmp;

  A = (float **)malloc( ndim * sizeof(float *));
  Atmp = (float *)malloc ( ndim * mdim * sizeof(float));
  for(i=0;i<ndim;i++)
    A[i] = &Atmp[i * mdim];

  for(i=0;i<ndim;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<mdim;j++)
    {
      A[i][j] = 0;
    }
    A[i][0] = 0.85 * (float)((i+1)*(i+1))/(float)(ndim*ndim);
    A[i][1] = 1.00 * (float)((i+1)*(i+1))/(float)(ndim*ndim);
  }   

  cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);

  cudaArray* cu_array;
  cudaMallocArray( &cu_array, &channelDesc, mdim, ndim );
  cudaMemcpyToArray( cu_array, 0, 0, Atmp, ndim * mdim *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
  tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;

  tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;

  tex.normalized = false;

  cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, cu_array, channelDesc);

  dim3 dimBlock(4, 4, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid(mdim / dimBlock.x, ndim / dimBlock.y, 1);

  float* d_data = NULL;
  cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_data, ndim * mdim *sizeof(float));

  transformKernel<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, 0 >>>(d_data, mdim, ndim);

  cudaMemcpy(Btmp, d_data, ndim*mdim*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

The desired output is:

```
1.33e-02 1.56e-02 2.43e-03 4.69e-04 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 4.91e-03 9.37e-03 
5.31e-02 6.25e-02 9.72e-03 1.88e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.97e-02 3.75e-02 
1.20e-01 1.41e-01 2.19e-02 4.22e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 4.42e-02 8.43e-02 
2.13e-01 2.50e-01 3.89e-02 7.50e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 7.86e-02 1.50e-01 
3.32e-01 3.91e-01 6.07e-02 1.17e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.23e-01 2.34e-01 
4.78e-01 5.62e-01 8.75e-02 1.69e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 1.77e-01 3.37e-01 
6.51e-01 7.66e-01 1.19e-01 2.30e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 2.41e-01 4.59e-01 
8.50e-01 1.00e+00 1.56e-01 3.00e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 3.15e-01 6.00e-01
```

And using the Texture memory I get:

```
1.33e-02 1.56e-02 2.43e-03 4.69e-04 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
5.31e-02 6.25e-02 9.72e-03 1.88e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
1.20e-01 1.41e-01 2.19e-02 4.22e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
2.13e-01 2.50e-01 3.89e-02 7.50e-03 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
3.32e-01 3.91e-01 6.07e-02 1.17e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
4.78e-01 5.62e-01 8.75e-02 1.69e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
6.51e-01 7.66e-01 1.19e-01 2.30e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 
8.50e-01 1.00e+00 1.56e-01 3.00e-02 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.00e+00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-memory) for the addressing mode:

> The *addressing mode*. It is valid to call the device functions of Section B.8 with coordinates that are out of range. The addressing mode defines what happens in that case. The default addressing mode is to clamp the coordinates to the valid range: [0, N) for non-normalized coordinates and [0.0, 1.0) for normalized coordinates. If the border mode is specified instead, texture fetches with out-of-range texture coordinates return zero. **For normalized coordinates, the wrap mode and the mirror mode are also available**. When using the wrap mode, each coordinate x is converted to frac(x)=x floor(x) where floor(x) is the largest integer not greater than x. When using the mirror mode, each coordinate x is converted to frac(x) if floor(x) is even and 1-frac(x) if floor(x) is odd. The addressing mode is specified as an array of size three whose first, second, and third elements specify the addressing mode for the first, second, and third texture coordinates, respectively; the addressing mode are `cudaAddressModeBorder`, `cudaAddressModeClamp`, `cudaAddressModeWrap`, and `cudaAddressModeMirror`; **`cudaAddressModeWrap` and `cudaAddressModeMirror` are only supported for normalized texture coordinates**

Since you are not using normalized coordinates:

```
tex.normalized = false;
```

the wrap mode is not available.